# Javascript How Get Value after running multiple IF statements

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, if-statement, for-loop

I have an `Object` that I want to loop through and run against a series of IF statements. Each IF statement makes an `HTTP Request`. The results of the `HTTP Request` gets pushed into an `Array`. I need to execute a function after looping through the object.

How do I execute a function ONLY after the Looping and IF statements are finished?

Code:

```
function myFunction(Object, res) {
    var resultArray;
    for (var obj in Object) {
        if (something is true) {
            //do something
            resultArray.push(result)
        }
    }
    //After the for loop is confirmed finished, do callback
    res(resultArray)
}
```

Comment: this will work, depending on what your `do something` is doing, if its doing animation or `get`s its not likely to work. Also dont use `Object` for variables, its a reserved word, pretty much

Comment: If you're `do something` is making these HTTP requests via ajax, make sure that you are going to do them synchronously. In other words, make sure you are getting the responses before you execute `res(resultArray)`. Also keep in mind that HTTP requests are expensive, would it be more efficient to send your Object to the server in 1 HTTP request and then send back the resulting array?

Comment: @Blowsie yes, variable name in my sample ar enot being used. This doesnt work because I am making an HTTP request and it move on before I get a response.

Comment: @Christopher.Cubells each of my IF statements are making a different http request to different end points. Its very possible that it will make 2-3 requests in the For Loop that I need to capture. In this situation I am ok with making the calls synchronously, but how would I do that? If I pass them to a new function, a) how does that function know that their could be more coming and b) I think I would lose access to make the callback.

Comment: @Rob: jQuery's ajax function has a parameter called `async` just set this to false. ex: `$.ajax({ url: "/getdata", async: false, success: function() { } })`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can still do this asynchronously. First you will need to get all the properties out of your object:

```
//Gather up all the properties;
var properties = [];
for(var property in object) if(object.hasOwnProperty(property) {
    properties.push(property);
}

//Array of results
var resultsArray = [];


//This is a named, self-invoked function that basically behaves like a loop. The
//loop counter is the argument "i", which is initially set to 0. The first if
//is basically the loop-termination condition. If i is greater than the
//total number of properties, we know that we're done.
//
//The success handler of the ajax call is where the loop is advanced. This is also
//where you can put your if condition to check if something is true, so that you
//can insert the data into the results array. At the end of the success handler,
//you basically call the named self-invoked function, but this time with the
//loop counter incremented. 
(function iterateOverProperties(i) {
    if(i < properties.length) {
        var property = properties[i];
        var value = object[property];

        //assuming jQuery just for demonstration
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "someurl",
            data: value;
            success: function(data) {
                if(something is true) {
                    resultArray.push(data);
                }

                iterateOverProperties(++i);
            }
        });
    } else {
        res(resultArray);
    }
})(0);
```